# Is it possible to clone sugarcrm modules?

Tags: sugarcrm

Is there any way to clone a SugarCRM module ?
For now it's a working Openqc module, it does include: quotes, products and sales.

I need the same module for purchasing, everything should be the same but it should just impact other tables to save purchase.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it is possible to clone a module. easiest way is to use an installable package and unzip it. then refactor the code, the folders and it's manifest file with the new module names.

Just changing the table names in the modules vardefs will not work as expected, because the table name should be the downcased module name.